# Issue with ampersand in Input element

Tags: html

I have a form element on my ASP page, and under the `<input>` element there is a `"value"` attribute, in which I have an email recipient.

However, the email address has an ampersand (&) in it, and I'm not sure how to encode it for a HTML attribute...any help would be appreciated.

I currently have this format, but I am not receiving the emails:

`<input type="hidden" name="recipient*" value="data&amp;info@example.com">`

Should I be using `%26` to encode it, or is `&amp;` correct? Or am I just doing it wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you should use `&amp;`

`%26` is used for URL encoding, when there's an ampersant in a parameter of the page, for example.

Answer (score 0):

`&amp;` should work fine, can you send/receive an email to that address manually?

Comment: I'll have to do some additional testing. Thanks for your help everyone.